# Cannot convert from initializer_list to my type, which has templated variadic constructor

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, variadic-templates, initializer-list

So, this isn't really something I **have** to do, I was just playing around. I wrote a `Vector` class for vectors of any numeric type and any number of coordinates. It is used as `Vector<NumericType, [num of coords]>`. Here is the code:

```
#include <array>
#include <functional>

namespace World {

template <typename NumType, unsigned char Size>
class Vector
{
public:
  using CoordType = NumType;


  template<typename... NumTypes>
  constexpr Vector(NumTypes&&... vals) : values{ std::forward<NumTypes>(vals)... }
  {
    static_assert(sizeof...(NumTypes) == Size, "You must provide N arguments.");
  }

  Vector(const std::array<NumType, Size>& values) : values(values) {}
  Vector(const std::array<NumType, Size>&& values) : values(std::move(values)) {}

  const NumType& operator[](size_t offset) const { return values[offset]; }
  NumType& operator[](size_t offset) { return values[offset]; }

  //! Converts all values to new given type
  template <typename NewType>
  constexpr Vector<NewType, Size> Convert() const { return Convert<NewType>(std::make_index_sequence<Size>{}); }
  //! Converts all values via the conversion function
  template <typename NewType>
  Vector<NewType, Size> Convert(const std::function<NewType(NumType)>& callback) const { return Convert<NewType>(std::make_index_sequence<Size>{}, callback); }

  std::array<NumType, Size> values;

private:
  //! Converts all values to new given type
  template <typename NewType, std::size_t ... Is>
  constexpr Vector<NewType, Size> Convert(std::index_sequence<Is...>) const { return { { static_cast<NewType>(values[Is])}... }; }
  //! Converts all values via the conversion function
  template <typename NewType, std::size_t ... Is>
  Vector<NewType, Size> Convert(std::index_sequence<Is...>, const std::function<NewType(NumType)>& callback) const { return { { callback(values[Is])}... } ; }
};
```

Now what I am trying to do now is to make sure that the conversion function declared above is working. The idea of usage is this:

```
using namespace World;
using Vector3D = Vector<double, 3>;
using Vector3Int = Vector<int, 3>;

#include <cmath>

int main()
{
  const Vector3D src{ 1.4, 2.5, 3.6 };
  const Vector3Int target = src.Convert<int>([](double val) { return (int)std::round(val); });
  return 0;
}
```

The issue here is that when the conversion function is compiled, the resulting new values appear in the form of `std::initializer_list<NewType>`. For some reason, this doesn't qualify for the constructor `Vector(NumTypes&&... vals)`. Now I do not want to have an initializer list constructor - the number of expected arguments is not variable, it must be whatever the `Size` template parameter says.

So how to get around this? How can I convert `std::initializer_list` to whatever `NumTypes&&... vals` is?

I must admit here I do not *precisely* know what I'm doing, I am trying to improve my C++ knowledge.

Comment: I haven't looked at it carefully but should the `Convert` function return like this: `return { {callback(values[Is])... } } ;` ?

Comment: OT: First, constant rvalue references do not make sense (especially, if you are trying to "move" from them later). Second, perfect forwarding for fundamental types also does not make sense. There is no difference between a copy and a move for types like `int` or `double`.

Comment: @TedLyngmo That worked, you're a genius! But the position of the dots was based on other code what works when they are behind the bracket... Could you maybe post an answer that explains the difference between `{{x...}}` and `{{x}...}`?

Comment: @TomášZato-ReinstateMonica Cool (simplified: `return {callback(values[Is])...};` should work too). I can't write an answer. A 3 hour meeting is starting now. I'll leave it up to someone else. :-)

Comment: @TomášZato-ReinstateMonica I see that noone picked up the ball so I tried to explain it by a using examples. I feel like I'm not doing a good job explaining it myself so I hope someone else makes a better answer (or improves on my answer if it's salvageable)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `Convert`, you have the parameter pack `Is` which you'd like to use in conjunction with `callback` and `values`.

Parameter pack expansion "*expands to comma-separated list of zero or more patterns*", so this is what you'll get when used with the values in your question:

`Is...`

```
0, 1, 2
```

`values[Is]...` => `values[0], values[1], values[2]`

```
1.4, 2.5, 3.6
```

`callback(values[Is])...` => `callback(values[0]), callback(values[1]), callback(values[2])`

```
1, 3, 4
```

And you want to create a *braced-init-list* like this:

```
{callback(values[0]), callback(values[1]), callback(values[2])}
// =>
{1, 3, 4}
```

So:

```
template <typename NewType, std::size_t... Is>
Vector<NewType, Size> 
        Convert(std::index_sequence<Is...>, 
                const std::function<NewType(NumType)>& callback) const
{
    return {callback(values[Is])...};
}
```